# Only Firefox ignoring 100% height with display: table-cell

Tags: html, firefox, gecko, css

I'm trying to vertically center an element by setting its parent to `display: table` and then the element to `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`. I'm also setting the height of the element to `34%` and its parent to `100%` so it fills the screen.

This is working perfectly well on every browser (including IE 8+) but Firefox. Firefox just ignores the height and collapses to the height of the span element.

Why would this be happening?

**CSS**

```css
#homeNav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#homeNav li {
  height: 34%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#homeNav li a {
  min-height: 177px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;
}
#homeNav li a.last {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#homeNav li a:hover, #homeNav li a.active {
  background: none;
}
#homeNav li a span {
  padding: 50px 0 50px 100px;
  display: block;
  background: url(../images/main-nav-hover_bg-large.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 120px 50px;
  padding-left: 160px;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take all the height declarations off: an item set to `display: table-cell` as a child of some element set to `display: table` should always be 100% height of its parent.

You also have `display: block` and `display: table-cell` on the same element. Even though the `display: table-cell` will take precedence (because it's last), you should try and keep your code clean.

The code below works in Firefox for me:

#### HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
div { display: table; height: 100px; border: 4px solid #000; width: 300px;}
a { display: table-cell; border: 4px solid #0f0; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; }
```

[Demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jUXy/).

Comment: upvoted to counter-act downvote. This answer seems to work, addresses OP's question, and is quite reasonable.